# (Flutter) How to change a RoundedRectangleBorder app bar "back" background color

Tags: flutter, appbar

The edges of the RoundedRectangleBorder app bar use the scaffold background color and display above the body widgets, which gives certain pages an unaesthetic look.
I can go around that by wrapping the scaffold in a container, but since I'm using one scaffold and a tab controller for AppBars and Body widget this became a hassle.
is there a way to give the app bar transparent back background color within the AppBar widget itself?

[image]

```dart
class ClosetAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      systemOverlayStyle:
          SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          bottom: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      leadingWidth: 75,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          child: Text(
            'My Closet',
            style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).title2.override(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        expandedTitleScale: 1.0,
      ),
      elevation: 2.0,
      actions: [
        Align(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => UploadClothingWidget(),
                    ));
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(60.0);
}
```

**EDIT**:
I realize I can just not use the scaffold widget at all which will work. this is the last result since I like the parameters I have from using it's template